# Cast Error when trying to read Web.config Config Section

Tags: c#, api, authentication, configuration, servicestack

I am trying to find out if it's possible to configure ServiceStack to authenticate a call using an API key in the host header?

I have found an example here: http://rossipedia.com/blog/2013/03/06/simple-api-key-authentication-with-servicestack/

but for some reason in my Clients.cs, which looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Servicestack_MVC.Models
{
public static class Clients
{
    private static Lazy<ClientSection> section = new Lazy<ClientSection>(() =>
          (ClientSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("apiClients"));

    public static bool VerifyKey(string apiKey)
    {
        return section.Value.Cast<ClientSection.ClientElement>()
               .SingleOrDefault(ce => ce.ApiKey == apiKey);
    }
}

}
```

I get the errors:

Error 9 Instance argument: cannot convert from 'Servicestack_MVC.Models.ClientSection' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable'
and

Error 10 'Servicestack_MVC.Models.ClientSection' does not contain a definition for 'Cast' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Queryable.Cast(System.Linq.IQueryable)' has some invalid arguments

In the  section of web.config I have added:

```
<section name="apiClients" type="ClientSection" requirePermission="false"/>
```

and added the section

```
<apiClients>
  <clients>
    <client name="Client1" apiKey="somelongrandomkey" />
    <client name="Client2" apiKey="somelongrandomkey" />
    <!-- etc -->
  </clients>
</apiClients>
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong please?

Many thanks

Comment: I have got a little closer I *think*. I have now changed the VerifyKey to the following:

    return section.Value.Clients.Cast<ClientSection.ClientElement>().SingleOrDefault(ce => ce.ApiKey == apiKey);

but now getting the error Error 9 Cannot implicitly convert type 'Servicestack_MVC.Models.ClientSection.ClientElement' to 'bool'

Comment: Oops! You're right, that's a typo on my post. It has been fixed.

Answer (score 2):

That's actually an error on my post. It's been fixed. The actual code should look like this:

```
public static bool VerifyKey(string apiKey)
{
    return section.Value.Cast<ClientSection.ClientElement>()
           .Any(ce => ce.ApiKey == apiKey);
}
```

Also, your configuration section handler needs to be fully qualified. From the looks of it, it seems you have placed the code in the `Servicestack_MVC.Models` namespace.

In that case, your `<section>` tag needs to look like this:

```
<section name="apiClients" type="Servicestack_MVC.Models.ClientSection" requirePermission="false"/>
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: perfect! - thank you very much! I ended up with the line return section.Value.Clients.Cast<ClientSection.ClientElement>().Any(ce => ce.ApiKey == apiKey);